# How to properly rotate bitmap?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, rotation

I have two bitmap, BitmapOriginal and BitmapSecond. After I merge the two bitmap successfully, My objective now is to rotate bitmapOriginal.

But the rotation is kinda weird, i dunno if I can call it rotation

[image]

Please check my code
XML
https://wtools.io/paste-code/b3kF

JAVA
https://wtools.io/paste-code/b3kG

Answer (score 0):

if you have set the bitmap to an imageView , test the setRotation() method for rotating the image.
for Example :

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
image1.setRotation(90);
```

please reply if solved your problem

Comment: Sorry it work only If I rotate the two bitmap, but I want to rotate one Bitmap only (BitmapOriginal). I want to make BitmapSecond steady(not moving) while BitmapOriginal rotating